# HP Envy + extended battery, intermittently cuts out power

Tags: laptop, battery, power, hp-envy

i got the big extended battery for HP Envy since i can only get 1HR of life from the regular one (fast cpu)..

after getting the extended battery, after 1-2 months of use, it would randomly just shut off power, and not come back on until i took all batteries out and put regular one back in.

the problem gotten worse and worse to the point where it would shut off during boot.

so i finally had HP replace the extended battery.

i used the replacement battery scarcely because i had a bad feeling about this.. and as this was maybe 8th time i used it, the power off just happened again. after resetting the initial battery (and keeping the extended off) i was able to power back on.

any ideas on how to troubleshoot what it is before i call HP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty obviously a hardware issue with either the battery or the battery receiver.  I would call HP.

Comment: i did call them. as i said, they replaced the battery. the problem seems to creep up after some use.

Comment: I don't think you will get a fix for it unfortunately.  It may be a design issue or an issue w/your particular unit.